# Twig condition inside AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twig

Here is what I have:

```
<p ng-class="{'hidden': infoDateRealis === undefined || infoDateRealis == '' }">
    Visit date: <br/>
    {[{dateBasket}]}<br/>
    {[{infoDateRealis}]}
</p>
```

I would like to print `dateBasket` only if `infoDateRealis` is empty.

Comment: What is the wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong,  this print dateBasket and infoDateRealis but i want to print dateBasket only if infoDateRealis is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator to evaluate an expression:

```
{{infoDateRealis ? dateBasket : ''}}
```

It can be interpretated as **if** `infoDateRealis` **then** display `dateBasket` **else** display `''`.

---

Another solution (maybe more readable) would be using [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)/[`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow):

```
<span ng-show="infoDateRealis">{{dateBasket}}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks the idea was nice.<br/>
Here is the solution I was looking for<br/>
`<div ng-hide="basketDatas.basket.dateBasket">{[{basketDatas.basket.infoDateRealis}]}</div>
          <div ng-show="basketDatas.basket.dateBasket">{[{basketDatas.basket.dateBasket}]}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Here i put **ng-if condition**, so this may work for you:

```
<p ng-if="!basketDatas.basket.infoDateRealis" ng-class="{'hidden': basketDatas.basket.infoDateRealis === undefined || basketDatas.basket.infoDateRealis == '' }">
    Visit date: <br/>
    {[{basketDatas.basket.dateBasket}]}<br/>
</p>
```